# Analytical solution coupled linear differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & \exp(-i\omega t) \\ \exp(+i\omega t) & -a \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\ y_2 \end{bmatrix},$$ with $y_1(t=0)=1$ and $y_2(t=0)=0$.
While it is straightforward to solve numerically, I was wondering if there is an analytical solution. Atleast, the matrix exponential seems analytically intractable.

Comment: There is an analytical solution.  For example, Wolfram Alpha will find it.  But that is not likely to be useful.

Comment: The substitution $y_{1,2}\sim \exp(\mp 0.5\omega t)$ could work.